# How to print command line execution output using java

Tags: java

While running below code prompt will open and it will show java version information. I want to print that java version information. please help me on this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"java -version\"");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        // Read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `System.getProperty("java.version")` or `System.getProperty("java.vm.version")`? Or was this just a testing ground for trying out command-line execution from Java?

Comment: this is one example my actual requirement is to read the result from command-line execution through Java and use in our code.

Comment: [Runtime.exec(String) is now deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)), for good reason.  The documentation recommends using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.  By doing so, you will be able to use [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) to make the subprocess’s output appear in the output of your Java program.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you read the stream the process might not actualy be done yet. I'm pretty sure you first have to wait `int exitVal = proc.waitFor();` on the process to finish before reading the outputStream.

for debugging wrapping part of this in a try with logging on the `proc.getErrorStream()` might help to